# how to use safe validation rule in yii2?

Tags: validation, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have some doubt about safe validator.There is four case

> i)I have some validation rule like below

```
[['name'], 'required','message' => 'You must enter name'],
```

In that case i want safe validation or it is enough

> ii)I have some validation rule with some scenarios like below

```
public function scenarios()
{
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_INFO => ['title', 'phone'],           
    ];
}
```

rule like that

```
[['title'], 'required','message' => 'You must enter Title','on' => 'info'],
```

In that case also i want safe validation or it is enough.

> iii)Third case i have only public property no validation rules apply in that property,but i want that property in form user will enter.
>
> iv)Fourth case i have only public property no validation rules apply in that property,and i don't want that property even form also,using only internally (i.e model).

In which cases the safe validation rule is must,i am new in yii so please explain easily understandable way.Thanks in advance

Comment: [Yii Wiki on safe validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/161/understanding-safe-validation-rules/)

Comment: @Insane Skull The above gives a detailed explanation about Yii 1.1, however OP mentioned Yii2 in question title. Although the core concepts remain the same, in Yii2 the process for massive assignment has changed.

Comment: thank u for spend your time @insane skull

Answer (score 0):

From the cases you have provided, it appears **case# iii)** will be the right situation for using `safe`.

For proper understanding please get your concepts clear about **Safe Attributes**, **Massive Assignments**. Refer to the links below:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#massive-assignment
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#safe-attributes